# работа со списками, игра похожая на зуму) #Python

Tags: python, циклы, for, while

Всем привет, есть задачка:
Есть 3 списка:

```
one = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]
two = [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1]
three = [3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
```

нужно из каждого списка удалять цифры, если их 3. И в конечном итоге должен остаться пустой список Three.

Моя попытка:

```
for i in one:
    if i == one.count(3):
        one.remove(i)
```

Должно получится:

```
one=[1, 2, 2, 1]
two=[1]
three=[]
```

Можете дать подсказку? Спасибо.

Comment: если их подряд три как в зуме или если их вообще три одинаковые в списке получилось?

Comment: Необязательно чтобы они чередовались, главное чтобы было 3 одинаковых цифра

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Циклы, срезы. Условия не пригодились.

```
one = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]

for i in one[:]:  # делаем копию списка с помощью среза для итерирования 
    cnt = one.count(i)
    for j in range(cnt - cnt % 3):
        one.remove(i)

print(one)
```

```
[1, 2, 2, 1]
```

*Старое:*

Собираем числа в словарь `число:кол-во повторений`, потом удаляем в цикле количество чисел, кратное тройке.

```
one = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]
two = [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1]
three = [3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]


def del_three(lst):
    d = {}
    for i in lst:
        x = d.get(i, 0)
        d[i] = x + 1
    for k, v in d.items():
        for i in range(v // 3 * 3): # или range(v - v % 3)
            lst.remove(k)
    return lst


print(del_three(one))
print(del_three(two))
print(del_three(three))
```

То же, но немного покороче с использованием `collections.Counter()`

```
from collections import Counter

one = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]
two = [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1]
three = [3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]


def del_three(lst):
    for k, v in Counter(lst).items():
        for i in range(v - v % 3):
            lst.remove(k)
    return lst


print(del_three(one))
print(del_three(two))
print(del_three(three))
```

```
[1, 2, 2, 1]
[3, 3, 1]
[2, 1, 1]
```

Результат в задачке корректный только первый, во втором списке пять троек, две должны остаться. В третьем аналогично.

Comment: Спасибо вам за отклик и за ответы, и дико извиняюсь, забыл написать, мне нужно выполнить задачу исключительно только с помощью циклов, условий  срезов, А словарь и функции к сожалению нельзя использовать :) а так решение - one[3:3+6] = []
two[:-1] = []
three[::] = []

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что такой результат не получится, если порядок цифр не имеет значения, а только сам факт наличия трех одинаковых в списке (согласно уточнению).

Если взять все эти списки и объединить, а потом убрать тройки одинаковых цифр, то останется список [1, 1, 3, 3]. Возможно, что-то не так с исходными данными. Мой код смог расстрелять список three по максимуму, чтобы в одном списке собрать три одинаковые цифры, а остатки переместил в список one.

```
from collections import Counter

one = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1]
two = [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1]
three = [3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]

for i in three:
    #   если в one/two лежит 2 или больше одинаковых числа
    if i in one and Counter(one)[i]>=2:
        one.pop (one.index(i))
        one.pop (one.index(i))
        three.pop (three.index(i))
    if i in two and Counter(two)[i]>=2:
        two.pop (two.index(i))
        two.pop (two.index(i))
        three.pop (three.index(i))

for i in three:
    #   если в one/two лежит 1 число, но при этом в three их два
    if i in one and Counter(one)[i]==1 and Counter(three)[i]>=2:
        one.pop (one.index(i))
        three.pop (three.index(i))
        three.pop (three.index(i))
    if i in two and Counter(two)[i]==1 and Counter(three)[i]>=2:
        two.pop (two.index(i))
        three.pop (three.index(i))
        three.pop (three.index(i))

for i in three:
    #   если в three остается 3 одинаковых числа, то убираем их
    if Counter(three)[i]>=3:
        three.pop (three.index(i))
        three.pop (three.index(i))
        three.pop (three.index(i))

#   выстреливаем остатки в one
for i in three:
    one.append(i)
three=[]

#   показываем остатки
print (one, ' ', two, ' ', three)
```

Возможно код и не дал ожидаемого результата, но отработал выстрелы лучше, оставив на одну цифру меньше. Если в список three для моего кода добавить еще одну 1 и одну 3, то партия будет разыграна в ноль.