# помогите что не так с кодом

Tags: python

нужно составить алгоритм на python который проверяет можно ли из элементов СТРОКИ n получить строку p путем перестановки или склеивания например:
n = привет
p = прив
ответ: да
у меня на выходе пишет нет

```
from itertools import *
a = str(input())
b = str(input())
s = len(b)
for i in permutations(a, s):
    if i == b:
        print('да')
    else:
        print('нет')
```

Comment: если у тебя есть конкрентный вопрос, то ты можешь его задать, нажав кнопу "Править" под вопросом. Тут не "помогают решить задачу", тут могут помочь тебе найти ошибку в твоем решении.

Comment: вам надо знать какие буквы и в каком кол-ве в строке p, а потом проверить, если достаточное количество нужных букв в строке n. Дерзайте

Comment: тут можно две строки (входные данные и нужная строка) перевести в список и потом во входных данных искать по букве из нужной строки, удаляя их из двух списков. Если по результату в списке, в который вы поместили ожидаемый результат не осталось ячеек, то значит можно. Этот принцип воспроизвел в ответе на вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499976/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%83-python?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

Исправил ваш код, теперь правильно ответ выдаёт (ввод можете раскомментировать, это просто пример работы):

```py
from itertools import permutations

a = 'привет' # input()
b = tuple('прив') # tuple(input())
s = len(b)
for i in permutations(a, s):
    if i == b:
        print('да')
        break
else:
    print('нет')
```

Суть в том, что сравнивать нужно одинаковые сущности. В данном случае `permutations` выдаёт кортежи, их и нужно сравнивать, для этого вторую строку я перевёл тоже в кортеж. Ну и `else` должно быть не на каждой итерации цикла, а после цикла, если ни разу не сработал `break`.